# nginx: fastcgiwrapper not showing stderr in error_log

Tags: c, nginx, fastcgi, stderr, error-log

I have set up a nginx server (`nginx version: nginx/1.6.2`) + fcgiwrapper (fcgiwrap version 1.1.0).
It's supposed to executed C programs on http requests.
The C programs are outputting html code to `stdout` and error messages to `stderr`.
(with `fprintf(stderr, "Some Message");`)

A few weeks ago, the output on stderr was always written to the `error_log` file from the nginx-config. However, since a few days I've noticed, that the Messages on `stderr` from my C-programs are no longer recorded in the nginx-error-log. I have not changed anything in the configuratoin considering `error_log` or `access_log`.

How can I log `stderr` from cgi-Programs to the nginx-error-log?

Comment: Have you tried restarting nginx?

Comment: I tried that (plus restarting the entire server)

Comment: Could it have something to do with the `-f` option in `fcgiwrapper`? (It's used in /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap. (this means it should forward `stderr` to nginx, doesn't it?)) So the error text should be visible in `error.log`.
I also tried other Programs (bash-script: `echo "Error" 1>&2`) but this didn't work either.